# Barplot from unorganised data - dataframe creation?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

From the table below, I need to create 4 different barplots, corresponding to the 4 diffeent places `TST1` `TST2` `TST3` `TST4` `TST5`

Each barplot should have 8 ticks for `NOT_DONE` `INCOMP` `UNTESTED` `30` `35` `40` `45` `50` in that order if possible. The ticks will correspond to the number of time each "value" appears for that given place. (The places are one of 4 options: `L1` `L2` `L3` `L4`)

**However:**

Only the values in the right-most column are to be considered meaning if no values are found in TST5, then the program should check TST4 etc until it finds a value. If no value is found in either of these 5 columns then no value is counted. If a value is found then it **does not** matter what is to the left of it.

My thought process for that would be to create a new column dataframe with the values I need (so the most right values for each row) and their corresponding place. I am new to all this and unsure how to do it so any help in which direction to go would be greatly appreciated.

I am required to use python 2.7, I am also using seaborn for the plotting.

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| PLACE | TST1     | TST2     | TST3     | TST4   | TST5     |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L1    |          | NOT_DONE |          |        | 50       |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L1    |          |          | 35       |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L4    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          |          | INCOMP   |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L2    | UNTESTED |          |          | INCOMP |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L4    |          | 30       |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          | INCOMP   | 40       |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L4    |          |          |          |        | UNTESTED |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L1    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          | INCOMP   |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L2    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L2    |          | 50       |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          |          | UNTESTED | 35     | NOT_DONE |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L1    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L2    |          | 40       |          | INCOMP |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L3    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L1    |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| L4    |          | NOT_DONE |          | 30     | NOT_DONE |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the expected output >

Comment: I've added an example showing more or less what I'd like the barplot for L3 to look like for example, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am required to use python 2.7, I am also using seaborn for the plotting.

Tested on python 2.7.18 and pandas 0.24.2 (though it works fine in python 3):

1. Propagate the right-most values (ignoring `PLACE`) using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) along `columns`:

   ```
   df['TST'] = df.drop(columns='PLACE').ffill(axis='columns').iloc[:, -1]
   ```
2. Group by `PLACE` and get their [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

   ```
   data = df.groupby('PLACE')['TST'].value_counts().reset_index(name='COUNT')

   #   PLACE       TST  COUNT
   # 0    L1        35      1
   # 1    L1        50      1
   # 2    L2    INCOMP      2
   # 3    L2        50      1
   # 4    L3    INCOMP      2
   # 5    L3        40      1
   # 6    L3  NOT_DONE      1
   # 7    L4        30      1
   # 8    L4  NOT_DONE      1
   # 9    L4  UNTESTED      1
   ```
3. Then pass this `data` into [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) (use the `order` param to set your preferred tick order):

   ```
   incompletes = ['NOT_DONE', 'INCOMP', 'UNTESTED']
   ticks = incompletes + sorted(data.TST.unique())[:len(incompletes)]

   g = sns.catplot(x='TST', y='COUNT', col='PLACE', col_wrap=2,
                   data=data, order=ticks, kind='bar')
   g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
   ```

   [image: catplot output]

---

Versions:

```
>>> sys.version
2.7.18 (default, Mar 15 2021, 14:29:03) \n[GCC 10.2.0]
>>> pandas.__version__
0.24.2
>>> matplotlib.__version__
2.2.5
>>> seaborn.__version__
0.9.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great and works exactly as intended. Say my number range was bigger than 30-50 and something more like 60-150. Would there be a more "elegant" way to write in the 'ticks=' line rather than input each number by hand? Writing them by hand is fine when they are few but not really when the range is much bigger.

Comment: @codingamat it's a bit tricky since if you want the words to come first. i updated the answer with one option: input the words by hand (`incompletes` list) and combine them with the sorted numbers (`sorted(data.TST.unique())[:len(incompletes)]`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This solution doesn't quite seem to work in my case, I have found a different way which works well. First, I used `num_range = list(range(60,151, 5))` then I used the same line of code you used for incompletes `incompletes = ['NOT_DONE', 'INCOMP', 'UNTESTED']` For the final line of code, I based mine on the one you used but changed it a bit: `ticks = incompletes + ([str(num) for num in num_range])`